# Copying by Looping cells in table merging with another range in 3rd range (concatenate)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a table and pull out cell data and combine it with a Range to create a flat (3rd) range.

Table1

> Sample A
>
> Sample B

Table2

> 123
>
> 456

Desired result

> Sample A 123
>
> Sample A 456
>
> Sample B 123
>
> Sample B 456

```
Sub LoopRange()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Set sht = Sheet25
lRow = sht.ListObjects("PlanName").Range.Rows.Count

Set MyRange = Sheet25.Range("i3:i10")
Set MyCell = Sheet25.Range(G3, "lRow")
 
For Each MyCell In MyRange
MyCell.Copy (k3) + MyRange.Copy(k3)
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of k3?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:  I put the output in column J.

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim MyRange2 As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sheet25 As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Integer



    Set sheet25 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet25")
    lRow = sht.ListObjects("PlanName").Range.Rows.Count
    currentRow = 12
    Set MyRange = sheet25.Range("i3:i10")
    Set MyRange2 = sheet25.Range("G3:G" & lRow)

    For Each mCell In MyRange

        For Each iCell In MyRange2
            Cells(currentRow, 10) = mCell.Value & " " & iCell.Value
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Next iCell

    Next mCell

End Sub
```